# How to address "Select-String -pattern" return object via pipeline without using foreach loop?

Tags: regex, powershell, pipeline

Let's say I have a file with a following content:

```
1,first_string,somevalue
2,second_string,someothervalue
n,n_nd_string,somemorevalue
```

I need to Get-Content of this file, get the last string and get the number before the "," symbol (n in this case). (I'll just increment it and append n+1 string to this file, but it does not matter right now). I want all this stuff be done with *pipeline* cascade

I have come to this solution so far:

```bsh
[int]$number = Get-Content .\1.mpcpl | Select-Object -Last 1 | Select-String -Pattern '^(\d)' | ForEach-Object {$_.matches.value}
```

It actually works, but I wonder if there are any ways of addressing *Select-String -Pattern '^(\d)'* return object without using the foreach loop? Beacause I know that the return collection in my case will only consist of a 1 element (I'm selecting a single last string of a file and I get only one match)

Comment: You might need a `-match` operator to get the first match only. Or `-replace`: `-replace '^(\d).*', '$1'`

Comment: hm, but how exactly do I apply -match or -replace operators in a pipeline? for example, after I get the last string of a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
$num = [int]((Get-Content .\1.mpcpl | Select-Object -Last 1) -replace '^(\d).*', '$1')
```

**Notes**

- `(Get-Content .\1.mpcpl | Select-Object -Last 1)` - reads the file and gets the last line
- `(... -replace '^(\d).*', '$1')` - gets the first digit from the returned line (**NOTE**: if the line does not start with a digit, it will fail as the output will be the whole line)
- `[int]` casts the string value to an *int*.

Another way can be getting a match and then retrieving it from the default `$matches` variable:

```
[IO.File]::ReadAllText($filepath) -match '(?m)^(\d).*\z' | Out-Null
[int]$matches[1]
```

The `(?m)^(\d).*\z` pattern gets the digit at the start of the last line into Group 1, hence `$matches[1]`.

Comment: I like the parentheses solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a csv to me...

```
import-csv 1.mpcpl -header field1,field2,field3 | select -last 1 | select -expand field1
```

output:

```
n
```

Comment: a good one, but this particular file may look like a csv file but it not necessarily should be it, so I decided to get more general solution for different data structures with one common feature -- line number at the beginning of each line.